# Repository of 250 MB with Rails App of 11 MB on Heroku how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a small rails app which, according to my Mac takes only 11MB of space.

When I upload to Heroku, if I'm reading it right, it's only uploading 9.92MB of files (I've reinitialised the repo) but this seems to turn into a repo sized 250.5MB and hence brings a warning with it. Can anyone help me with how this is possible? Are the gems I'm using possibly bloating things? Can I find out where the space is being used on Heroku?

I've cleared github and re-pushed it. I have done `git count-objects -v` and received the following:

```
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 1073
packs: 1
size-pack: 10185
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0
```

Thanks in advance ..

My output from upload is:

```
Counting objects: 1074, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (882/882), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1074/1074), 9.92 MiB | 104.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1074 (delta 130), reused 1072 (delta 129)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Using CFPropertyList 2.3.1
remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.2
remote:        Using minitest 5.5.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Using rack 1.6.0
remote:        Using mime-types 2.4.3
remote:        Using arel 6.0.0
remote:        Using addressable 2.3.8
remote:        Using request_store 1.1.0
remote:        Using ffi 1.9.8
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.10
remote:        Using execjs 2.4.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.11.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using buftok 0.2.0
remote:        Using hitimes 1.2.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1
remote:        Using connection_pool 2.1.3
remote:        Using sass 3.4.13
remote:        Using equalizer 0.0.11
remote:        Using multipart-post 2.0.0
remote:        Using excon 0.45.1
remote:        Using net-ssh 2.9.2
remote:        Using ipaddress 0.8.0
remote:        Using inflecto 0.0.2
remote:        Using geocoder 1.2.8
remote:        Using grocer 0.6.1
remote:        Using hike 1.2.3
remote:        Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
remote:        Using kgio 2.9.3
remote:        Using libv8 3.16.14.7
remote:        Using mini_magick 4.0.4
remote:        Using naught 1.0.0
remote:        Using formatador 0.2.5
remote:        Using newrelic_rpm 3.11.1.284
remote:        Using pg 0.18.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.7.12
remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Using ice_cube 0.11.1
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Using oj 2.12.1
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
remote:        Using raindrops 0.13.0
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Using redis 3.2.1
remote:        Using ref 1.0.5
remote:        Using simple_oauth 0.3.1
remote:        Using temple 0.7.5
remote:        Using yard 0.8.7.6
remote:        Using will_paginate 3.0.7
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using memoizable 0.4.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Using mail 2.6.3
remote:        Using faker 1.4.3
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using rack-protection 1.5.3
remote:        Using ffi-compiler 0.1.3
remote:        Using jmespath 1.0.2
remote:        Using fission 0.5.0
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 5.1.8
remote:        Using timers 4.0.1
remote:        Using uglifier 2.7.1
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.3.0
remote:        Using mailchimp-api 2.0.6
remote:        Using faraday 0.9.1
remote:        Using net-scp 1.2.1
remote:        Using sprockets 2.12.3
remote:        Using http 0.6.4
remote:        Using unicorn 4.8.3
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using redis-namespace 1.5.2
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Using therubyracer 0.12.1
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.1
remote:        Using slim 3.0.3
remote:        Using fog-json 1.0.0
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.1
remote:        Using aws-sdk-core 2.0.37
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.4.1
remote:        Using scrypt 1.2.1
remote:        Using celluloid 0.16.0
remote:        Using fog-core 1.30.0
remote:        Using sinatra 1.4.6
remote:        Using twitter 5.14.0
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.3
remote:        Using rabl 0.11.6
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.1
remote:        Using aws-sdk-resources 2.0.37
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Using fog-xml 0.1.1
remote:        Using fog-brightbox 0.7.1
remote:        Using fog-local 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-serverlove 0.1.1
remote:        Using fog-sakuracloud 1.0.0
remote:        Using fog-softlayer 0.4.1
remote:        Using fog-storm_on_demand 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-vmfusion 0.0.1
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.1
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.1
remote:        Using carrierwave 0.10.0
remote:        Using aws-sdk 2.0.37
remote:        Using sidekiq 3.3.3
remote:        Using fog-atmos 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-aws 0.1.1
remote:        Using fog-ecloud 0.0.2
remote:        Using fog-profitbricks 0.0.2
remote:        Using fog-radosgw 0.0.3
remote:        Using fog-riakcs 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-terremark 0.0.4
remote:        Using fog-voxel 0.0.2
remote:        Using authlogic 3.4.5
remote:        Using sidetiq 0.6.3
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.1
remote:        Using fog-powerdns 0.1.1
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.1
remote:        Using fog 1.29.0
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.1
remote:        Using railties 4.2.1
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.2.4
remote:        Using bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails 0.3.3.6
remote:        Using responders 2.1.0
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
remote:        Using versionist 1.4.1
remote:        Using rails 4.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.3
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Your bundle is complete!
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
remote:        Bundle completed (0.72s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (5.32s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web, worker
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 250.6MB
remote: -----> Warning: This app's git repository is large.
remote:        Large repositories can cause problems.
remote:        See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#repo-size
remote: -----> Launching... done, v811
```

Comment: Heroku is installing all the dependency libraries you use into it's repository, and you are using a lot...

Comment: When you `bundle` app locally, all gems and dependencies are installed in user's `$GEM_PATH`. That's why you don't see the size increasing _inside_ your repo. When you push and deploy the app on Heroku (or others), it installs the gems etc in `vendor` directory of repo. See: `bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment` above.

Comment: I'd try bundling into a path locally, and check the size of it. Yours doesn't seem excessively large for a Rails app, but there is no way of telling without actually installing it...